# Stop Jquery Mobile from Reinitialize the Page When Back Button Click?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am handling the Back/Forward button myself in jquery mobile. The problem is that when a user click back button then jquery send ajax request and reinitialize the page which mess up all my work. I have set `data-backbtn="false"` and  `$.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;` But none of these trick works for me. Any idea?

Comment: And what is reinitialize to you?

Comment: @Gajotres It will set the complete html with the ajax response. I want to this behavior

Comment: Ok I got it, did you initialize $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false; inside a mobileinit event?

Comment: @Gajotres, yes inside pageinit

Comment: No, pageinit is not the same thing like mobileinit. I will write you an answer hot to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have ended up using this line which worked for me,

```
$(window).off('popstate');
```

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem is also in **$.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;** handling.

That code sample MUST be triggered from mobileinti event like this:

```
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function () {
    $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
});
```

One more thing, mobileinit event MUST be triggered before jQuery Mobile is initialized, like this:

```
<script src="http://www.dragan-gaic.info/js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>      
<script>
        $(document).bind("mobileinit", function () {
            $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
        });    
</script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
```

### Example:

**HTML 1 :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>jQM Complex Demo</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; minimum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=no; target-densityDpi=device-dpi"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
    <script src="http://www.dragan-gaic.info/js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script> 
        <script>
                $(document).bind("mobileinit", function () {
                    $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
                });    
        </script>         
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>   
</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="index">
        <div data-theme="a" data-role="header">
            <h3>
                First Page
            </h3>
            <a href="second.html" class="ui-btn-right">Next</a>
        </div>

        <div data-role="content">

        </div>

        <div data-theme="a" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">

        </div>
    </div>    
</body>
</html>
```

**HTML2 :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>jQM Complex Demo</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; minimum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=no; target-densityDpi=device-dpi"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
    <script src="http://www.dragan-gaic.info/js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script> 
        <script>
                $(document).bind("mobileinit", function () {
                    $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
                });    
        </script>         
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>   
</head>
<body>    
    <div data-role="page" id="second">
        <div data-theme="a" data-role="header">
            <h3>
                Second Page
            </h3>
            <a href="index.html" class="ui-btn-left">Back</a>
        </div>

        <div data-role="content">

        </div>

        <div data-theme="a" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">

        </div>
    </div>    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery Mobile removes pseudo-pages from the DOM after they are navigated away from (this is for external pages only). You can stop this behavior on a single pseudo-page by adding the data-dom-cache="true" attribute to the `data-role="page"` element for the pseudo-page:

```
<div data-dom-cache="true" data-role="page">
    ...
</div>
```

There are other ways to enable (well disable really I guess) this functionality; you can read about them  [here](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0.1/docs/pages/page-cache.html)